# R - removing rows based on two criteria in data frame

Tags: r, duplicates, plyr

I have a data frame with home sales and 12000 obs and 20 variables. I am trying to remove any sales with the same Address and sale dates within 30 days of each other. The reasoning is that visual inspection of data has revealed these "duplicate" sales within 30 days of each other sales are likely recording errors by MLS. Therefore, I am not including them in the regression analysis. I have left the dates as numeric to help when creating the range of sale days criteria. These are the two relevant columns of my data frame:

```
Address      SellingDat
120 N.Main   41540
305 S.Hill   42530
2243 Ridge   40002
120 N.Main   41530
```

I am trying to find all duplicate addresses that have sale dates within 30 days from each other, and then remove them from the data frame

So far I have tried using the following, but don't full understand what it is doing other than basic idea of creating a new data frame with unique values.

```
data2 <- ddply(data, .(Address, SellingDat), unique)
```

Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated. I have read discussions related to this but haven't found anything that I can figure out how to apply based on what I am trying to do. I am a newbie in R, and more than anything want to learn how the code works, and not just have a piece of code that works. Thank You!

Comment: I think you need to be a little more specific. You say "remove them from the data frame" - do you want to remove both or keep one? If keep one, which one? What if a single address has 3 selling dates, each 20 days apart - do you want to remove the last one even though it is 40 days after the first one?

Comment: Hopefully this will help clarify. Remove all rows where: one address has multiple sales (rows) & a sale date (column) is within 30 days of another one of its own sale dates. I do not want to keep either of the two rows because they are considered unreliable observations. To answer your 3 selling date scenario, remove all 3 because the criteria is "within 30 days of another sale date". I understand what you were getting at there, but isn't going to be a concern in my case. Thank You

Comment: This is just a small piece of the larger code. The purpose of it is kind of a "broad" stroke way to check for "human" errors in the data set. I realized I needed to do this when visually looking through the data. One house might have 3 entries in less than a month with sale prices, number of bedrooms, or number of bathrooms varying significantly between each sale records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your responses to my comment keep this pretty easy. Here's some slightly larger sample data:

```
data = data.frame(
    Address = c('a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd'),
    SellingDat = c(1, 1, 10, 50, 90, 10, 20, 1, 100)
)
data
#   Address SellingDat
# 1       a          1
# 2       b          1
# 3       b         10
# 4       b         50
# 5       b         90
# 6       c         10
# 7       c         20
# 8       d          1
# 9       d        100
```

Then we can use `dplyr` to calculate, by Address, the differences from the previous and to the next selling dates. Then we filter to keep only rows where the previous and next selling dates are more than 30 days away.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% group_by(Address) %>%
    arrange(SellingDat) %>%
    mutate(time_to_next = c(diff(SellingDat), NA),
           time_from_last = c(NA, diff(SellingDat))) %>%
    filter(coalesce(time_to_next, Inf) > 30 & coalesce(time_from_last, Inf) > 30) %>%
    select(-time_to_next, -time_from_last) %>%
    arrange(Address, SellingDat)
# Source: local data frame [5 x 2]
# Groups: Address [3]
# 
#   Address SellingDat
#    <fctr>      <dbl>
# 1       a          1
# 2       b         50
# 3       b         90
# 4       d          1
# 5       d        100
```

Coalesce replaces missing values, so I coalesce with `Inf` to make sure missing values are kept.

Comment: Thank You! I am very grateful for your time and explanation.